# Ignite SqlQuery for two clients

Tags: sql, ignite

I use next process for my Ignite cache with third party persistence:

1. empty database
2. start two instances in server mode
3. start first instance in client mode.
4. The client in cycle

   - creates entities
   - reads entities by a simple SqlQuery

So far all right. All the code works properly.

Then I start second instance in client mode. The code is the same.
The second client also in cycle

- creates entities
- reads entities by the SqlQuery

And the second client gets empty ResultSet. While the first client still reads the data properly. BTW. Both clients can get entities by keys.

Off course all the data in memory.

So why the second client can't read by SqlQuery?

Three options of code are below. All of them work identically: The first started client always gets correct result. The second started client always gets empty ResultSet.

```
    SqlQuery<EntryKey, Entry> sql = new SqlQuery<>(Entry.class, "accNumber = ?");
    sql.setArgs(number);
    List<Cache.Entry<EntryKey, Entry>> res = entryCache.query(sql).getAll();
```

...

```
    SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("select d_c, summa from Entry where accNumber = ?");
    sql.setArgs(number);
    List<List<?>> res = entryCache.query(sql).getAll();
```

...

```
    SqlQuery<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> query = new SqlQuery<>(Entry.class, "accNumber = ?");
    QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>> entryCursor = binaryEntry
            .query(query.setArgs(number));
    List<javax.cache.Cache.Entry<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>> res = entryCursor.getAll();
```

XML configuration is below:

```
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <!-- Set a cache name. -->
                <property name="name" value="entryCache" />
                <!-- Set cache mode. -->
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL" />
                <!-- Number of backup nodes. -->
                <property name="backups" value="1" />

                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder"
                        factory-method="factoryOf">
                        <constructor-arg
                            value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcEntryStore" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true" />

                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <!-- Setting indexed type's key class -->
                            <property name="keyType"
                                value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.EntryKey" />
                            <!-- Setting indexed type's value class -->
                            <property name="valueType" value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.Entry" />

                            <!-- Defining fields that will be either indexed or queryable. Indexed 
                                fields are added to 'indexes' list below. -->
                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="key.accNumber" value="java.lang.String" />
                                    <entry key="key.d_c" value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.EntryKey.DEB_CRE" />
                                    <entry key="key.valuedate" value="java.util.Date" />
                                    <entry key="summa" value="java.lang.Integer " />
                                </map>
                            </property>

                            <!-- Defining indexed fields. -->
                            <property name="indexes">
                                <list>
                                    <!-- Single field (aka. column) index -->
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="key.accNumber" />
                                    </bean>
                                </list>
                            </property>

                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

Comment: Could you share the query you run?

Comment: It's still not clear to me, what you're doing. Please share full code, for example - pom based project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for suggestions.

I achieved an option which gives a stable and correct result.

Actually I moved the field **accNumber** from the key class to the value class. So now select is filtered against a primitive field of the value class.

Query configuration:

```
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                        <!-- Setting indexed type's key class -->
                        <property name="keyType"
                            value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.EntryKey" />
                        <!-- Setting indexed type's value class -->
                        <property name="valueType" value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.Entry" />

                        <!-- Defining fields that will be either indexed or queryable. Indexed 
                            fields are added to 'indexes' list below. -->
                        <property name="fields">
                            <map>
                                <entry key="accNumber" value="java.lang.String" />
                                <entry key="key.d_c" value="ru.raiffeisen.cache.repository.EntryKey.DEB_CRE" />
                                <entry key="key.valuedate" value="java.util.Date" />
                                <entry key="summa" value="java.lang.Integer " />
                            </map>
                        </property>

                        <!-- Defining indexed fields. -->
                        <property name="indexes">
                            <list>
                                <!-- Single field (aka. column) index -->
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                    <constructor-arg value="accNumber" />
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>

                    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a Third party store, readThrough works only for key-value API, for SQL you need to run [loadCache method](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-loadcache-) before performing queries on Ignite.

If you want to use read from disk with persistence, I would recommend using Ignite native persistence store: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Also, I see in you configuration:

```
 <property name="indexedTypes" value="true" />
```

It's definitely a mistake, it should be configured like:

```
<property name="indexedTypes">
    <list>
        <value>java.lang.Integer</value>
        <value>java.lang.Long</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

IndexedTypes and QueryEntity configure the same things, actually, internally, IndexedTypes will create a configuration of QueryEntity. So, it's redundantly to configure both.

Comment: All data are in the cache. Both clients are working in the same environment, with the same code, with the same data.

Comment: Could you share a reproducer?

Comment: Added some thoughts about things that could affect this behavior

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is a wrong line. Indeed there is no this statement in the real configuration. It is a copy-paste mistake. I've adjusted the description.